# Create Vec<String> from literal

Tags: rust

I want to do

```
fn main() {
    let options: Vec<String> = vec!["a", "b", "c"].map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect();
}
```

because this seems like the easiest way to get a vector of owned `String`s, but I get hit with this error:

```
error: no method named `map` found for type `std::vec::Vec<&str>` in the current scope
...
note: the method `map` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
`std::vec::Vec<&str> : std::iter::Iterator`, `[&str] : std::iter::Iterator`
```

I don't see where the need for the `[&str] : std::iter::Iterator` bound comes from. if you ignore the part with `split_whitespace` I'm basically doing what answers on [this question](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-how-to-convert-vector-of-raw-strings-to-struct-string/6024) recommend.

How should I be generating this vector?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> if you ignore the part with `split_whitespace`

Yes, except you cannot ignore this part. [The docs for `split_whitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_whitespace) state (emphasis mine):

> The **iterator returned**

`split_whitespace` returns an [iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) over the pieces of the string that were separated by whitespace, and [`map` is a method on `Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map).

A `Vec` is not an iterator. You can see that `Vec` does not implement it's own `map` method:

> no method named `map` found for type `std::vec::Vec<&str>`

And the compiler tries to suggest what you *might* have meant, but weren't quite achieving:

> note: the method `map` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:

You can get an iterator from a `Vec` by calling [`Vec::iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) or [`into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_iter):

```
fn main() {
    let options: Vec<String> = vec!["a", "b", "c"].into_iter().map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect();
}
```

---

However, there's no need to allocate two vectors here, an array and a vector is more efficient:

```
let options: Vec<_> = ["a", "b", "c"].iter().map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();
```

An [iterator over a slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) returns references (`&T`) to the elements in the slice. Since each element is already a `&str`, the type of `s` is a `&&str`. Calling `to_owned` on a reference to a reference simply clones *the reference*. You could also have said `.map(|&s| s.to_owned())`, which *dereferences* the value once, producing a `&str`. Calling `to_owned` on a `&str` allocates a `String`.

Comment: Why do I have to use `.to_string()` in your last example? If I use `.to_owned` I still end up with a Vec<&str> so you're definitely onto something...

Answer (score 2):

If I had to create vectors of `String`s repeatedly, I would use a macro:

```
macro_rules! vec_of_strings {
    // match a list of expressions separated by comma:
    ($($str:expr),*) => ({
        // create a Vec with this list of expressions,
        // calling String::from on each:
        vec![$(String::from($str),)*] as Vec<String>
    });
}

fn main() {
    let v1 = vec_of_strings![];
    let v2 = vec_of_strings!["hello", "world", "!"];

    println!("{:?}", v1);
    println!("{:?}", v2);
}
```

Output:

```
[]
["hello", "world", "!"]
```

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks, I searched for a simple syntax. The `as` keyword is still mysterious for me. I do not know when I can use it because `From`/`Into` do not permit to use it.